# Using objects as the values of an Enum?

Tags: python, enums

I'm currently trying to create an enum/constant-based system for defining colours in Python. I want to avoid having to use strings when attempting to use/access a colour.

In an ideal world, I want to be able to do:

```
>>> print(Colours.BLACK)
Black

>>> print(Colours.WHITE.hex)
ffffff
```

So far, I have come up with an enum and object based system like the following:

```
from enum import Enum

class Colour:

  def __init__(self, name, hex = "000000"):
    self.name = name
    self.hex = hex

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Colours(Enum):
  WHITE = Colour("White", "ffffff")
  BLACK = Colour("Black", "000000")

print(Colours.BLACK.value)

print(Colours.WHITE.value.hex)
```

which prints:

```
Black
ffffff
```

However, something about assigning an object as the value of an enum feels like poor practice and I have not seen this done before elsewhere.

Is this considered bad? If so, why?

And is there a better way of achieving my desired outcome?

**Edit:**

I ended up going with this approach, using `__hash__` as suggested by @MichealButscher and using `__str__` and `__repr__` to avoid using `.value`.

```
from enum import Enum

class Colour:

  def __init__(self, label, hex_value = "000000"):
    self.label = label
    self.hex_value = hex

  def __str__(self):
    return self.label

  def __hash__(self):
    hash(self.label)


class Colours(Enum):
  WHITE = Colour("White", "ffffff")
  BLACK = Colour("Black", "000000")

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.value

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.value)
```

Comment: "Colour" should define a `__hash__` function to mark its objects as immutable (documentation should also state that). Then it is in my opinion perfectly fine to use complex objects in an enum. Integers are also objects in Python, by the way.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Great suggestion, thank you for the insight.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Does a `__hash__` method really imply immutability? According to my understanding, it doesn't. Or am I misunderstanding what you're writing?

Comment: @myke I was a bit sloppy about that. Actually an immutable class should try to make its member variables inaccessible from the outside, usually by prepending `__` (which technically doesn't prevent access but makes it harder only). The `__hash__` implementation makes it more obvious that the class is immutable. The precise rules for making an immutable class are documented at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for clarifying. BTW, a frozen dataclass is also an option to build an immutable class.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is an object, so *some* object will be assigned. However, you can use *just* the color name and hex value in a tuple as the value, and have `Colour.__init__` handle initializing each instance with the tuple.

```
class Colour(Enum):
    WHITE = ("White", "ffffff")
    BLACK = ("Black", "000000")

    def __init__(self, label, hexvalue):
        self.label = label
        self.hexvalue = hexvalue
```

(Warning: certain attribute names are already in use and cannot be overridden or even assigned to, as you'll see if you try to, for example, use `name` instead of `label` and `value` instead of `hex value`.)

Comment: You are mistaken. `name` and `value` are *not* already in use and would work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I will go with my original solution but take your advice onboard with renaming the variables. It works with these names but may be confusing when accessing the name of the colour (i.e. `Colours.WHITE.value.name` when `Colours.WHITE.name` is something else)

Comment: @martineau: you are both right: `name` and `value` could be used for member *names*, but they cannot be used for other member *attributes*.

Comment: @chepner: you don't need the parentheses in the member definitions.

Comment: @Ethan: You are mistaken, we can't both be right. BTW, I also think the parens are fine ([PEP 20](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/): "Explicit is better than implicit").

Comment: @martineau: My reply was too long; it's included at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: `name` and `value` are defined in `Enum.__dict__`, and attempts at assignments like `self.name = label` produces an `AttributeError`. While I suppose you could shadow them with something like `self.__dict__['name'] = ...`, I doubt it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

@ethan-furman @martineau

You can overcome the issue with the pre-used name attribute by using `property` decorators and storing the name to a different attribute under the hood:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Colour(Enum):
    WHITE = 'White', "ffffff"
    BLACK = 'black', "000000"

    def __init__(self, name, hex):
        self._name = name              # no uh-oh anymore
        self.hex = hex

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def label(self):
        return self._name_
```

```
>>> Colour.WHITE
<Colour.WHITE: ('White', 'ffffff')>

>>> Colour.WHITE.name
'White'

>>> Colour.WHITE.label
'WHITE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a need for a separate color class, just combine it all into the enum:

```
from enum import Enum

class Colour(Enum):
    WHITE = "ffffff"
    BLACK = "000000"
    #
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and in use:

```
>>> Colour.WHITE
<Colour.WHITE: 'ffffff'>

>>> str(Colour.WHITE)
'WHITE'

>>> Colour.WHITE.value
'ffffff'
```

---

@martineau, @chepner is saying the following will fail:

```
from enum import Enum

class Colour(Enum):
    WHITE = 'White', "ffffff"
    BLACK = 'black', "000000"
    #
    def __init__(self, name, hex):
        self.name = name              # uh-oh
        self.hex = hex
    #
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and indeed it does:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AttributeError: <enum 'Enum'> cannot set attribute 'name'
```

I think what you were saying is that the following will work:

```
class Example(Enum):
    name = 'a name member'
    value = 'a value member'
```

In use:

```
>>> list(Example)
[<Example.name: 'a name member'>, <Example.value: 'a value member'>]

>>> Example.name.name
'name'
```

If you weren't saying that, then you were wrong.  :-/

As far as PEP 20 goes, commas are explicit.

Comment: That is what I meant. As for the commas, whether they create a `tuple` is context-sensitive so I think making clear what's going on is fine esp when answering questions here (to a probable Python noob).

Comment: @martineau: You're probably right -- I just hate extraneous parens.